# Smarty relative include path in subfolders

Tags: templates, smarty, smarty2

I have file structure like this:

```
templates
  index.tpl

  module_1
     main.tpl
     xyz.tpl
     abc.tpl
  ...
  module_n
     main.tpl
     zzz.tpl
     kkk.tpl
```

Smarty templates dir is: `$smarty->template_dir = USER_ROOT."/templates";`

Inside each module template `main.tpl` should include others templates from the same folder.

I've tried to include like this: `{include file="./kkk.tpl"}` but this does't work. How can I include templates from the same folder using relative path?

I use Smarty 2.6.24

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a variable `$moduleName` and use it (dont forget about double-quotes):

```
{include file="$moduleName/kkk.tpl"}
```

or try to use short form of `{include}`:

```
{include './kkk.tpl'}
```

See http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl (section *Example 7.53. {include} with relative paths*)